# how to change #gosetup command in goland?

Tags: go, go-modules, goland

when I sync dependencies is run command below:

```
GOROOT=/home/work/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/work/go #gosetup
/home/work/go/bin/go mod tidy #gosetup
```

i want to run:

```
GOROOT=/home/work/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/work/go #gosetup
/home/work/go/bin/go list -m -json all #gosetup
```

how to edit the command

Comment: Why do you need to change that? What are the problems that you encounter with the IDE running `go mod tidy` and what would running ` go list...` would solve in this case?

Comment: @dlsniper because there is a dependency in my project used has some import error, it's unit test has import error so ```go mod tidy``` report the error and failed ,but i can ```go mod download``` and download the dependencies and then compile, and the dependency is private and i cannot fix it